# How to count the number of a specific letter in a sentence?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to count the number of the letter a is in the word banana

```
def count_letters(letter, ch):
    '''count the letter a in the fruit'''
    count = 0
    for char in letter:
        #when char equals a then and 1 to count
        if char == "ch":
            count += 1
    return count
print(count_letters("banana", "a"))
```

But when I run the code I get 0

Comment: Why are you testing to see if `char` is "ch"? Just change that to ch.

Comment: @HIKMATBITTAR, if one of the below solutions helped, feel free to accept, so others can see a tested solution.

Comment: @HIKMATBITTAR, you should not change your question to a new question when your original question was answered. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I've rolled it back to the original question as it invalidated the 3 answers you received.

Answer (score 4):

One reason your code doesn't work is because you are comparing `char` in your function to a constant instead of your input `ch`. Below are three ways your algorithm can be implemented.

**For loop**

```
def count_letters(letter, ch):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        if letter[i] == ch:
            count += 1
    return count

count_letters('banana', 'a')  # 3
```

**collections.Counter**

```
from collections import Counter    
Counter('banana')['a']  # 3
```

**Generator expression**

```
sum(i=='a' for i in 'banana')  # 3
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> if char == "ch":
> ```

You are checking if char is equal to "ch", literally.

The correct thing to do is:

```
if char == ch:
```

Comment: Thank you, I was doing it so fast I couldn't see the error

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are not counting for the presence of letter 'a' from your script. Also how can you expect a single char to match set of more than one character.

Correct way would be :

```
char == ch
```